# Convert a string to typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object called `resolvers` which contains a list of functions that must be generated dynamically. The idea is to construct a sting and then convert it to typescript code, but I'm not sure we can do that. Here is an example of the code that must be generated:

```
const resolvers = {
Query: {
    // we must generale the list of those functions (bellow) dynamically 
    info: () => 'teeeeest',
    feed: () => links,
    get: (root, args) => {
        let indLink = links.findIndex((el) => el.id === args.id);
        return links[indLink];
    }
},
```

The string is generated at runtime using the results of a query. It will look something like this:

```
strCode: string = `info: () => 'teeeeest',
    feed: () => links,
    get: (root, args) => {
        let indLink = links.findIndex((el) => el.id === args.id);
        return links[indLink];
    }`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say dynamically, are the strings known at compile time or only at runtime?

Comment: the string is generated using the results of a query, which means the string is generated at runtime.

Comment: And what is to be generated? The names of the functions? Their output? Their arguments? Could you give an example?

Comment: i updated the question, all of what you said must be generated, the names, the code and the arguments

Comment: Are you generating JavaScript, or TypeScript? JavaScript is trivially easy to `eval` at runtime, TypeScript is definitely not.

Comment: why not just write that string to temp file and then call `tsc tempFile.ts` or just import it on runtime? or just use: `ts-node tempFile.ts`  and get the output?

Comment: @meagar we want to use typescript

Comment: You really can't. TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript, there is no TypeScript at runtime, only JavaScript. Any TypeScript code you generate at runtime is going to require you to include the entire TypeScript compiler and dynamically invoke it at runtime, which is probably not really a viable solution.

Comment: @cascadox yeah for that kind of thing you'd need `eval`. Unless you are creating trivial functions that just return hardcoded primitives, if you are actually specifying logic you can't do that without using `eval`.

Comment: ok i'll try eval and come back to you, thanks all

Comment: @cascadox Note that the advice to use `eval` only works with JavaScript. You cannot `eval` TypeScript, unless it happens to be a blob that is coincidentally also valid JavaScript.